# How to group weeks together and then aggregate values in common for the weeks?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I am having some difficulty in solving this question on aggregating weeks together. I have explored some solutions like:

```
SELECT metric, period_start_date,
       to_char(period_start_date - 7/24,'IYYY'), to_char(period_start_date - 7/24,'IW') 
FROM DATES
GROUP BY metric, period_start_date,
      to_char(period_start_date - 7/24,'IYYY'), to_char(period_start_date - 7/24,'IW');
```

But from the Oracle docs, this seems to be grabbing the week starting as Monday rather than an arbitrary date I choose like Sunday instead.

My question is how can I select weeks and have a count e.g. the highlighted in yellow of weeks that get represented as a count. After the count, how do I then group them say 40 and 41, 41 and 42; and then thereafter grouping/summing the rows if they are exact matches e.g. for the shop BangBang, the item type and size must be the same for it to be joined otherwise it remains as a distinct row.

Really stuck and would appreciate any insight!

[image: Table to convert]

Comment: Please edit your question to show a sample of the input data. Also, please show the output you would want for that sample data.

Comment: Hi @john-rotenstein, what do you mean by a sample of the input data and output data besides the image?

Comment: Please show a sample of the data you have in the table and, for that sample data, please show us the output you would like from the query. The sample output you have provided above does not match the "Current Table Data", so it is hard to write a query for you. For example, it is not clear how to generate `period_start_date` shown in the Desired Table Data. Therefore, please show the input data and the exact output data you would like to get for that input data.

Comment: Hi @john-rotenstein, the period_start_date in the desired table comes from the period_start_date in the current table. What I would like is to have the period_start_date be counted if it is in the grouped week. So for example, the first week of the period_start_date in the desired table is from Week 40. I did not include a row in the current table but what I was trying to imply was that if there was a week 40, it would be week 40. If there isn’t/then it should be really week 41-42 and the next is week 43-44 until the end if it is odd e.g. week 45. Does that help explain it?

Comment: Please supply a sample input dataset and also the sample output you would want from the query for that given input data.